# Why is a 15-qubit IBM quantum computer not working correctly?

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, error-correction, ibm-quantum-devices

I just wanted to implement an algorithm for adding two 2-bit binary numbers. And it works, but only on an IBM 32-qubit simulator. And on a real 15-qubit computer, ibmq_16_melbourne, it produces very strange results.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Or maybe the quantum computer is so noisy?

[image: Result_1]

I also tried to rewrite the algorithm for the structure of this computer, so that the qubits used in one operation are connected or are quite close.

[image: ibm]
[image: circuit_2]

But it didn't help.

About the algorithm:
qubits 0-2 are the result. Qubits 3-4 are the first number. Qubits 5-6 are the second number. The remaining qubits play the role of transfer flags.
I set qubits 3 and 5 to one using the NOT operation (I didn't understand how to apply units to them in another way). So at the output of the algorithm, I should get "010". But I get basically a different result.
[image: circuit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be a lot of swapping and additional gates during the execution of your circuit since CCX is not a native gate. The actual circuit that is being executed is something like:

[image]

This circuit has 11 qubits and depth of 79  and close to 100 CNOT gates, this is way too much for current hardware. Below is the noise level for Melbourne.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to develop an algorithm (circuit) for adding two 2-bit binary numbers so that it works correctly on 15-qubit IBM Melbourne?